# Bing Maps SharePoint Web Part with Service Refrence

Tags: c#, silverlight, sharepoint, linq-to-sql

I have a SilverLight application that uses a Linq-to-SQL service refrence. My service refrence is located at `http://localhost:1832/PositionService.svc`

When I start my project as a SharePoint Web Part this service is not a part of the SharePoint module. So it is not accessable because only the ".xap"-file is uploaded to SharePoint.

Can anyone give hints or help out in my problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you upload the .xap, you should still be able to access the service but you have to make sure that the SharePoint user account has permission to access the service and you also have to add any necessary configurations settings, such as assemblies to be loaded and other,  to Sharepoint-80 web.config file.

Comment: Is it not possible to add the service to the .xap-file?

Comment: As long as you have the proxy class and provide the valid url of the service when you create the object you should not have any problem.  You may want to have a look at this example:  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2010-Calling-f017b47f/view/SourceCode#content

Comment: How can I include this as a Web Part? What is the url of the .xap-file?

I tried http://hve85/WCF_CallServiceFromWebPart/WCF_CallServiceFromWebPart.xap but it gave me a 404 error.